# trying to copy a c string in a struct using only C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memcpy

I'm trying to insert a hard coded string into a char array value in a struct using only C, so I used memcpy, following the example in another post. But for some reason, I keep getting what looks like an address as output, I'm not sure why.

my console prints out: [ (2,7532592) (1,7524424) ] and other long numbers like that every time. I've checked so many examples on how to copy a sequence of characters into a c string, and it seems like this one was exactly the same. I might just be having trouble understanding pointers. Im not sure why it's spitting out the address value. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I apologize for any lack of knowledge on my part. My shortened down code is below:

```
struct node  
{
   int key;
   char month[20];
   struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

//display the list
void printList()
{
   struct node *ptr = head;
   printf("\n[ ");

   //start from the beginning
   while(ptr != NULL)
   {        
        printf("(%d,%d) ",ptr->key,ptr->month);
        ptr = ptr->next;
   }

   printf(" ]");
}

//insert link at the first location
void insertFirst(int key, char * month)
{
   //create a link
   struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   link->key = key;

   memcpy(link->month, month, 20);
   link->month[19] = 0; // ensure termination

   //point it to old first node
   link->next = head;

   //point first to new first node
   head = link;
}

int main() {

   insertFirst(1,"Jan");
   insertFirst(2,"March");

   printf("Original List: "); 

   //print list
   printList();
}
```

Comment: Note `link->month[19] = 0;` is a good idea to insure null character termination.  Consider alternatives that avoid _magic numbers_. `memcpy(link->month, month, sizeof link->month); link->month[sizeof link->month - 1] = 0;` or `link->month[0] = 0; strncat(link->month, month, sizeof link->month);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 printf("(%d,%s) ",ptr->key,ptr->month);
```

instead for the "curious output" problem.

Comment: gave you best answer since you were first

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the pointer `ptr->month`, not the actual string.
Try: `printf("(%d,%s) ",ptr->key,ptr->month);` (`%s` instead of `%d`).